# Зачем мы передаем в функцию параметр request?

Tags: django

```
def index(request, cat_id):
    if cat_id == None:
        cat = Category.objects.first()
    else:
        cat = Category.objects.get(pk=cat_id)
    goods = Good.objects.filter(category=cat).order_by('name')
    s = 'Категория.: ' + cat.name + '<br><br>'
    for good in goods:
        s = s + '(' + str(good.pk) + ')' + good.name + '<br>'
    return HttpResponse(s)


urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^(?:(?P<cat_id>\d+)/)?$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^good/(?P<good_id>\d+)/$', views.good, name='good'),
)
```

Объясните пожалуйста подробней что этот параметр в себе несет? Откуда он вообще взялся и почему без него нельзя.

Answer (score 2):

Это объект запроса. Когда запрашивается страница, Django создает этот объект, который содержит различные данные о запросе. Там хранятся методы(GET, POST), заголовки и т.д. Тебе лучше пройти в документацию. Есть [на русском](http://djbook.ru/rel1.8/ref/request-response.html)